# Javascript - String contains commas and dashes

Tags: javascript, html

I have a quick question.

How do I check whether there are any commas or dashes in a string? Thx

Comment: You can use indexOf() method. It will return -1 if there is not any character which you are searching.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
/[,\-]/.test(yourString)
```

this returns true if `yourString` contains commas or dashes or false otherwise.

Comment: Works. Anyway is the backslash in front of the dash necessary?

Comment: dash in square brackets if for ranges. It would work in this particular case (or at least works in Chrome) but if you want to test for commas, dahses and for example letter `a` and wrote `/[a-,]/` it would break.

Answer (score 2):

```
/(,|-)/.test(yourString); // returns true if there are commas or dashes in the string, false otherwise.
```

Comment: dosen't matter for data tye here. its work perfect for string as well as number

Answer (score 1):

You can use the indexOf() method to check the presence of a substring inside a string. If the return value is greater or equal to 0 there is at least one occurrence of the substring :

```
var str1 = "my-string";
var str2 = "string, mine";
var str3 "simple";

str1.indexOf("-"); //returns 2
str2.indexOf(","); //returns 6
str3.indexOf("-"); //returns -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var n = str.indexOf("some. text, here");
```

The indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string.

This method returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Just checking index of , or -

Example code:

```
var str="dhfdshf-43sf";
if(str.indexOf('-')!=-1){
//- exist
}

var str2="dhfdshf,43sf";
if(str.indexOf(',')!=-1){
// , exist
}
```

Comment: Shoudln't it be str.indexOf('-') >= 0) ? As you wrote it, the code inside the if blocks will be the occurrence when there is NO commas or dashes ?

Comment: Sorry my mistake i forgot :)  should be >=0 or != -1 .You are right :)